# Could not find or load main class SortingRuntime

Tags: java

Main method from `SortingRuntime.java`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner localScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Big-Oh visualizer!");
    System.out.println("Enter the number corresponding to what input size you want to sample");
    // More code ...
 }
```

The class `SortingRuntime` has a main method, but this error occurs:

[image: Error]
[image: Error]

Another thing that `SortingRuntime.java` does is extends `Application`.

Please help!

Comment: Your classpath is wrong? Is the `SortingRuntime.class` (not `.java`) file in the current directory? You did remember to compile first, right? --- Also, do not post links to images of your code. Copy/paste code to the question text and [format it correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Hey @Andreas I did compile it first before running the java command and the class name and it still won't work. I'm in the right directory and as you can see in the first image, the code has main. It's not in a package so there's no complexity in running the file. I'm stumped.

Comment: If you do `ls`, you see both `SortingRuntime.java` and `SortingRuntime.class`? And if you then run with `java -cp . SortingRuntime` you still get that error? Have you also tried just a simple "Hello World" program, just to be sure your Java installation is good? See [The Java™ Tutorials - "Hello World!" for Solaris OS and Linux](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/unix.html)

Comment: I can run java on anything else. For SortingRuntime, I was given only the class, I used a decompiler see a form of the .java file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I was using the Ubuntu package `default-jdk`. I installed Oracle's jdk and added `JAVA_HOME` to the `/etc/environment` file and `SortingRuntime` worked. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the directory where your java class `SortingRuntime.java` is present.

- Compile the class using below command

  `javac SortingRuntime.java`
- Run the class using below command and include the classpath

  `java -cp .: SortingRuntime`

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply! I've done exactly all that and it still says cannot find SortingRuntime. My friend has the exact same files in the exact same directory and his runs just fine. I've concluded that this could be a software issue. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS while my friend is running Mac OS X. Any thoughts?

Comment: You mean, you have compiled it and used `-cp .:` option as well wile running java command?

Comment: Yes, it's really annoying.

Comment: Yes it does @Rao

Comment: I'm in `~/Downloads/stuff` and the contents of `stuff` are `Sorting.class`, `SortingRuntime.class`, `TenXer.class`, `SoftwareEngineer.class`, `Cfo.class`, and `Ceo.class`. All these classes are required to run `SortingRuntime.class`. I've tested the classes not including `SortingRuntime.class` in a separate file called `Test.class` which has its own main method. I took out `SortingRuntime.class` before compiling and running `Test.class` for safe measure and everything works as expected. `SortingRuntime.class` is the only thing not working.